# What should be changed in this infinite scroll code to prevent post overlapping?

Tags: html

I am new to javascript and I really need help with masonry and infinite scroll on my Tumblr page. My older posts keep overlapping everytime I scroll to the bottom of my page to load them.

Can anyone fix the code for me so that masonry is not applied until the posts are done loading?

I have tried (over 10 times now) to fix the code myself but something else ends up getting messed up on my page and the issue does not get resolved.

This is the current infinite scroll code I am using:

```
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#content');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'}),
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination',
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : '.entry',
loading: {
finishedMsg: '',
img: 'https://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/pX1lrxdsa8xv/ajax-loader.gif'
},
bufferPx : 600,
debug : false,
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){$newElems.fadeIn(300);} );});});});</script>
{/block:IndexPage}
```